# sum object values in separate array in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

im new in VueJs and i have on object that includes some array in there like below and i want to show sum off all amount in one of the column table
my table :

```html
<tr v-for="(transaction,index) in transactions" >

<td>{{ index }}</td>

<td>show sum of all amount here</td

</tr>
```

and transaction is :

```html
026b148e-c7dd-4891-b4d1-15a492c971a4: [
{
id: 106,
type: "income",
created_at: "2020-06-28 13:44:08",
updated_at: "2020-06-28 13:44:08",
amount: 10,
description: null,
type_of_pay: "group",
invoice_number: "026b148e-c7dd-4891-b4d1-15a492c971a4",
},
{
id: 107,
type: "income",
created_at: "2020-06-28 13:44:08",
updated_at: "2020-06-28 13:44:08",
amount: 1,
description: null,
type_of_pay: "group",
invoice_number: "026b148e-c7dd-4891-b4d1-15a492c971a4",
package: {}
}
],
```

how can i do what i want simple and clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a computed property called sum that returns the sum of all transactions and use that in the template may be?

```
computed: {
    sumOfTransactions() {
        return this.transactions.reduce((sum, transaction) => {
            return sum += transaction.amount;
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

And, use that in the template as

```
<td>{{ sumOfTransactions }}</td>
```

Comment: thank to you but i do it before and i have this error: TypeError: this.transactions.reduce is not a function, each transaction have many object in there @prashant

Comment: @Amirali reduce is an array function, since transactions is an object you'll first need to grab the object keys `Object.keys(this.transactions)...`